# Microsoft Edge Process ID changes, how to change/keep track of it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app that will be acting like a desktop, with certain apps available, such as Microsoft Edge browser. I am able to open multiple windows of it, add a button to a custom taskbar, but the problem is, you could find the process by name, but then the buttons/program doesnt know which correct window to open. And if I search by ID, VS gives me:

```
System.ArgumentException:'Process with an Id of #### is not running'
```

Since Microsoft it self, changes the ID of the initial ID that it starts with.

So the methods right now im using for trying to get the right window is:

```
public void NewTabClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //NewTabClick is a click event that gets created with every new button
            MessageBox.Show("NewTabClicked");

            ShowWindow(GetWindowHandle(), 3);

        }


private IntPtr GetWindowHandle()
        {
            try
            {
                //Here is where i get the exception error
                return Process.GetProcessById(ProcessId).MainWindowHandle;

            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
```

ProcessId is set when we start the app itself in another method like this

```
 private void StartApp()
        {
            
                var process = Process.Start(ProgramPath);
                SetProcessId(process);
            

        }
private void SetProcessId(Process process)
        {
            ProcessId = process.Id;
        }
```

Is there a way to keep track/change/update which ID it should look for, or another way to keep track of these windows/browsers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One trick is when you initially get the handle to the process window, change the name using SetWindowText (user32.dll) to something unique and then you can search for it easier in a list of processes.

Comment: @KevinCook I tried this, but when you are opening a new window of the same app (for example Microsoft edge), the text resets to the default one, any tips?

Comment: Do you mean you are opening a new window from your process? Or the user is opening a new window from within Edge?